# Backbone relational - how is it possible to find related model by two foreign keys?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

In my model i've defined relationship, so it's property with foreign key is substituded by related model.

I had an idea to give away from database two same values, for example `relatedId` and `related` - if i define models relationships for field `related`, `relatedId` value will be left untouched - and i will be able to use it.

Is it possible somehow to use collection.where() method in backbone relational on model attributes, that represent related models (they have object data type)? if i define related id - like following - it does not work:

```
collection.where({
    related : 14 // this property contains related model, but not id after backbone initializes, i've also tried to use relatedId key instead - this does not work
})
```

I need such method very much, because i have to find models by lot of attributes, and it is very hard to do it from scratch :/

Could you please advice a way?

Answer (score 0):

I really like using database "views" to effectively flatten relationships for way easier querying. It works well.